# Crystal-Reports XI - sub report unwilling to split over two pages

Tags: crystal-reports

I have checked and "keep together" is not ticked. I have un-checked this within the details section of my sub report but still makes no difference + I have also tried "blank page before" option with a formula of 1 = 2 but had no joy

...any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but this of for anyone else looking for this same answer:

Go into Format SubReport, uncheck the Keep Together on the Common tab.

Answer (score 0):

More information?  What happens to the report/ subreport?  Does the rest of the subreport "disappear" across the main report page boundary?  Does the subreport not expand to fill the main report?  Does the subreport run past the page boundaries (tries to print down into the page footer)?

There are multiple places to set "Keep Together" behaviour:  the main report section that the subreport lives in (Section Expert, "Keep Together"); the subreport format options (right click on subreport, Format Subreport, "Keep Object Together"; and sections in the subreport. The

Also, make sure the sub-report is set to Can Grow.